# GitLab CI/CD deploy AWS EC2

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm not sure that my ci/cd configuration file is correct
Actually I was trying a lot of ways, but it still return log `aws: not found` at the gitlab pipline

this is my .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: amazon/aws-cli:latest

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "ap-northeast-2"
  AWS_ECR_REGION: "us-east-1"
  ECR_REGISTRY: "public.ecr.aws/{here_id}"
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "access_key"
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "secret_key"

before_script:
  - aws ecr-public get-login-password --region $AWS_ECR_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $ECR_REGISTRY

build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:latest
  script:
    - docker build -t frontend_repo .
    - docker tag frontend_repo:latest $ECR_REGISTRY/frontend_repo:latest
    - docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/frontend_repo:latest
  only:
    - main

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:latest
  script:
    - docker stop frontend_container
    - docker rm frontend_container
    - docker rmi $ECR_REGISTRY/frontend_repo:latest
    - docker pull $ECR_REGISTRY/frontend_repo:latest
    - docker run -t -d -p 80:3000 --restart unless-stopped --name frontend_container $ECR_REGISTRY/frontend_repo:latest
    - docker logs -f frontend_container
```

The main target is connectiong to the AWS -> build & push docker image to AWS ECR -> pull & run docker container on the EC2 instance

for the first look, script seems correct, but I can't connect to the AWS, even with using amazon/aws-cli image as execution environment

Does anyone could check possible issues?
The required variables has been added to GitLab CI/CD variables

Comment: Although you have declared the aws-cli image as the default, you are overriding it in each job with `image: docker` -- the docker image doesn't have AWS CLI installed, so you'll probably want to install it as part of your job using the apk package manager in the image. Alternatively, use an image which has all the utilities you need.

Comment: Yes, I already got similar advice about image with all required utils, but actually, I'm not sure which one could I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been solved by `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$VARIABLE_NAME_SAVED_IN_GITLABCI_SETTINGS`
`export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$VARIABLE_NAME_SAVED_IN_GITLABCI_SETTINGS`
on build stage before aws get login

Also I have used amazon/aws-cli image on build stage and then I'll installing docker

Also it was been needs a service as docker:dind for using it inside aws image on build stage